# Загрузка в одну кнопку

Tags: php, javascript, html

Доброго времени суток !

Встал такой вопрос: Как загрузить изображение в один клик ?

Пример: Нажал на кнопку "выбрать изображение" на сайте, вылезает окошко с выбором файлов на компьютере пользователя, когда изображение выбрано после нажатия кнопки "Открыть" в браузере, должна произойти работа обработчика.

Comment: Для таких целей, нужно использовать `javascript`- событие `onchange`.

Comment: @And, спасибо, теперь буду копать в этом направлении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Как загрузить изображение в один клик ?

---

Сделать загрузку в один клик можно с помощью вызова события `onchange`.

В моем случае надо было загрузить фото и сделал так:

```
<input type="file"onchange="myScript();" accept="image/*">
```